# Charge density with proportional radius?

Tags: electrostatics

$Q$ is evenly distributed over the volume of a ball of radius $a$ so that the space charge density is proportional to the distance $r$ from the center of the ball. Ie $ρ_v = kr$ where $k$ is a constant. I'm supposed to show that $p_v=kr$

attempt

$$\int E\cdot dA=\int \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2\epsilon_0}\cdot 4\pi r^2=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

This is where i'm stuck. Should I use spherical coordinates and just

$$\int \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}d\tau$$
or $$\iiint \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}\cdot \rho^2 \sin\phi \, d\rho \, d\theta \, d\phi \, ?$$

Comment: What other information do you have? It seems like you don't have enough

Comment: @Triatticus That's the only information i'm given, besides that we have a Total charge $Q$ and i'm supposed to find the electrical field $E$ everywhere when ....$Q$ is evenly etc....

Comment: For charge densities in 1-, 2- , 3-dimensions we usually have  the terms linear, surface, volume charge density and the symbols $\;\lambda, \sigma, \rho \;$ respectively. In your question you have $\;\rho=\text{constant} \;$ or
$\;\rho(r)=\text{constant}\cdot r \;$  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: see comments below, there appears to be a misunderstanding of the question set - I shall update this answer to better reflect what OP actually asked when I get the chance later**

(I'm not sure what you mean by "space charge density", but I'm assuming you want the $\mathbf{E}$ field as you say in your comment).

You need to use Gauss' law, which is
$$\int\int\mathbf{E}\cdot\text{d}\mathbf{S} = \frac{Q_\text{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
The easiest way is to exploit the symmetry of the situation and consider a "test sphere" of arbitrary radius $r$, through which $\mathbf{E}$ field lines are passing through perpendicularly.  The flux through this test sphere (which is the left hand-side of Gauss' law) is
$$\int\int\mathbf{E}\cdot\text{d}\mathbf{S} =|\mathbf{E}|\int\int\text{d}S = A_\text{sphere}|\mathbf{E}|= 4\pi r^2|\mathbf{E}|$$
Where the first step above is true, because the electric field lines are alway parallel to the normal of your test surface sphere.

$Q_\text{enc}$is the charge enclosed in our test sphere, which is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho$, where $\rho$ is the constant charge density.  From that, you find that the electric field strength is indeed proportional to $r$ (at least inside the sphere).

Comment: if i were to find the electric field of it knowing that the radius is proportional.

Comment: would it be $E=\frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho}{\epsilon 4\pi r^2}$

Comment: $E=\frac{r\rho}{3\epsilon}=>E=\frac{r^2k}{3\epsilon}$?

Comment: No sorry I may have confused you with my notation, my $\rho$ is probably different to your $\rho$ in your question - my $\rho$ is the charge density of the sphere (which I have assumed to be constant).  Perhaps it is something different, though I'm not quite sure to what it is referring, sorry.

Comment: my $\rho$ or $\rho_s$ is the surface charge density

Comment: Ok, I think I understand - you're supposed to show that the surface charge density is proportional to the radius of the spherical object, which itself is a ball of uniform charge, $Q$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first step is finding the electric field as per my answer above, which as far as I can tell is still all valid.  To continue on though would need a few more steps, so perhaps I (or someone else if they're willing to jump in) would need more thinking time...

Comment: My bad for being so confusing i translated the wrong problem. I want to find the electrical field $E$ given that  $Q$ is evenly distributed over the volume of the sphere with radius $a$so that the electric charge density is proportional with the distance $r$ from the spheres centrum and i'm given that the $\rho_v=kr$ where $k$ is a constant

Comment: I'm given a hint that we can find $k$ by solving $Q=\int \rho dV$ and that the Geometri of this problem makes it so that its a wise choice to work in spherical coordinates

Comment: I think the confusion here is your phrase "$Q$ is evenly distributed over the volume of the sphere".  To me, that suggests that the charge density is constant, but now I'm thinking it is in fact proportional to $r$, and this will change the problem dramatically.  I think the solution is still similar to that above, but now $Q_\text{enc}=\int\rho\text{d}V$ (as your hint says), which you can indeed evaluate with spherical polar coordinates as you suggested in your question initially.  Since the system is spherical, the $\theta$ and $\phi$ parts integrate to $4\pi$ and you're left with...

Comment: $Q_\text{enc}=4\pi\int kr^3\text{d}r$.  I hope you can get somewhere with this? (I don't have too much time right now to give a full detailed solution, but I can edit my answer later to reflect my new understanding of the question).

Comment: I think i can get somewhere with this. The proper way would be to solve the integral then plug in $Q_{enc}$ into the gaussian and then solving for the electric field right?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do